# Same function to any numbers of inputs elements javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple elements like this:

```
<input type="text">
```

And I want to add slashes (`/`) so the output is a date mask.

I am using the following function, which only applies on IDs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fecha").keyup(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 2){
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
        }else if ($(this).val().length == 5){
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
        }
    });
```

How can i modify the above function to do a date format mask?

Comment: Use selector `"input[type=text]"`

Comment: Look for a [datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or date [mask](http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/) plugin - you'll save a ton of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all `input type="text"` elements within parent element where `keyup` event handler should be called on. You can alternatively set a common `.className` at the elements and use `.className` selector `$(".date")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form input[type=text]").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length == 2) {
      $(this).val(this.value + "/");
    } else if (this.value.length == 5) {
      $(this).val(this.value + "/");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```